# How to get gradle and Junit5 to use test classes that are named *Should?

Tags: gradle, junit, junit5

The gradle plugin for Junit5 looks for test classes that are named "*Test". Ours are also name "*Should", but are not detected. How can I get gradle to pick them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle) ...

> **Configuring Filters**
>
> You can configure filters for the test plan by using the filters extension. By default, all engines and tags are included in the test plan. Only the default `includeClassNamePattern (^.*Tests?$)` is applied. You can override the default pattern as in the following example. When you specify multiple patterns, they are combined using OR semantics.

```
junitPlatform {
    // ...
    filters {
        engines {
            include 'junit-jupiter'
            // exclude 'junit-vintage'
        }
        tags {
            include 'fast', 'smoke'
            // exclude 'slow', 'ci'
        }
        packages {
            include 'com.sample.included1', 'com.sample.included2'
            // exclude 'com.sample.excluded1', 'com.sample.excluded2'
        }
        includeClassNamePattern '.*Spec'
        includeClassNamePatterns '.*Test', '.*Tests'
    }
    // ...
}
```

I suspect you'll need to specify `includeClassNamePattern '.*Test', '.*Should'`